# Return records that are not in a query

Tags: sql, db2

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table.Diet
WHERE Diet.Date NOT IN (

SELECT Diet.Date
FROM Table.Diet
WHERE Diet.FruitsEatenToady = 'Banana'
Group BY Diet.Date)
```

Many fruits can be eaten in a single day.

But the query is returning days with in which banana's were eaten.

I'm new to db2 is there another syntax I can use for not in? Maybe some grouping?

Thanks

Edit Diet Table layout

```
  DATE-----FruitsEatenToday--Calories
  3/11/2014|Apple          | 116
  3/11/2014|Banana         | 106
```

Edit 2 totally butchered that first query updated it

Comment: What is the schema of your Diet table, and what types of values does the FruitsEatenToday column hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your table structure and query requirements, it looks like you need an anti-join:

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM Table.Diet AS d1
LEFT JOIN Table.Diet AS d2
ON d1.Date = d2.Date
AND d1.FruitsEatenToday <> d2.FruitsEatenToday
AND d2.FruitsEatenToday = 'Banana'
WHERE d2.FruitsEatenToday IS NULL
```

Comment: Brian you magnificent hombre! Killed it.

Word of the Day: anti-join

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the days when no bananas were eaten.  As your query is now written, the following would seem to work:

```
select *
from table.diet
where not exists (select 1
                  from table.diet
                  where Diet.FruitsEatenToady = 'Banana'
                 );
```

This will return all rows in `table.diet` when a banana is eaten today.  It will return no rows, if no banana is eaten.

This seems like a very strange data structure.  I would expect to see a table that has a date column and a fruit column, specifying what days a fruit is eaten.